# Add datasource to Report Builder using ODBC

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, ssrs-2008, openedge, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create a datasource in Report Builder using an ODBC connection (Progress OpenEdge 10.2B Driver)
I've set up the connection and created a User DSN. Tested the connection and got a connection established success message so pretty sure it's set up correctly in ODBC Data Source Administrator.

When I try to add the data source in Report Builder, I'm selecting the option to "Use a connection embedded in my report" and select connection type of ODBC from the Connection Type lookup.

For the connection string, I can select the data source name that I set up, add in my user name and password, but when I test the connection, I get the following error:
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect] [ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Insufficient information to connect to the data source. 
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect] ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver] Insufficient information to connect to the data source.

I must be doing something wrong but can't see anything obvious. Any advice would be greatfully received.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few KB articles that might help you:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/5796

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/7460

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/9314

Another option is that the user you are using to connect to the database with doesn't have SELECT privileges. This KB gives you details on how to do that: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P101721